# Reshaping dataframe using wide_to_long vs melt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to reshape my pandas dataframe, and recently came across the `wide_to_long`-function. In what cases would you prefer this function compared to the `melt`-function?

Comment: What does your dataframe looke like? The current question is a bit too broad. `wide_to_long`  mostly applies when you have suffixes in the names, `melt` when you don't.

Comment: I know, it's intended as a general question, more out of curiosity, able to do my thing with the `melt`-function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) is typically useful when you have repeated column names with common suffixes. The function automatically extract the suffix (you can specify the exact format with a regex).

Assuming this example:

```
   id  value1  value2  group1  group2
0   1       5       9      13      17
1   2       6      10      14      18
2   3       7      11      15      19
3   4       8      12      16      20
```

You can run:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['value', 'group'], i='id', j='type')
```

Output:

```
         value  group
id type              
1  1         5     13
2  1         6     14
3  1         7     15
4  1         8     16
1  2         9     17
2  2        10     18
3  2        11     19
4  2        12     20
```

It's actually described in the documentation to be "*Less flexible but more user-friendly than melt.*".

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) is thus lower level, you would need to post-process your output, from:

```
df.melt(['id'])
```

Output:

```
    id variable  value
0    1   value1      5
1    2   value1      6
2    3   value1      7
3    4   value1      8
4    1   value2      9
5    2   value2     10
6    3   value2     11
7    4   value2     12
8    1   group1     13
9    2   group1     14
10   3   group1     15
11   4   group1     16
12   1   group2     17
13   2   group2     18
14   3   group2     19
15   4   group2     20
```

To:

```
tmp = df.melt(['id'])
tmp2 = tmp['variable'].str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)')
(tmp.assign(col=tmp2[0], type=tmp2[1])
    .pivot(index=['id', 'type'], columns='col', values='value')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
         group  value
id type              
1  1        13      5
   2        17      9
2  1        14      6
   2        18     10
3  1        15      7
   2        19     11
4  1        16      8
   2        20     12
```

Note that you could also use MultiIndex reshaping:

```
out = (df.set_index('id')
         .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
                                    d.columns.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)'),
                                    names=[None, 'type']), axis=1))
         .stack()
       )
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pd.melt(df, id_vars=id)`? Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: `pd.melt(df, id_vars=id)` and `df.melt(id_vars=id)` are equivalent. I prefer to use the dataframe methods when avaibable.

Comment: Didn't know, thanks!